# Ubuntu installer showing partition but not accessible

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, boot-partition

I shrunk around 50 GB of my drive E, but when I'm going for Ubuntu installation, the partition is named as "unusable" and I'm unable to access it to create root and home partitions. What could be the problem?

Comment: Can you provide more information about the other partitions on that disk? If it is formatted MBR style and you have 4 primary partitions you will not be able to make a 5th without making an extended partition.

Comment: Yes. It is formatted MBR style and I have 4 primary partitions with windows on it. How do I make an extended partition?

Answer (score 0):

You need to complete the following steps. If you don’t know how to do them ask other questions. This assumes the partition you have shrunk is not a windows system partition.

1. Backup or move your data on the the partition you have shrunk (E:). This could be a simple cut and paste operation if you have enough space somewhere else temporarily.
2. Delete that partition.
3. Create a new extended partition using all the available space.
4. Create a new logical partition (E:) in the extended partition for the data you backed up.
5. Restore your data
6. Check it’s all working

You should then be able to start your Ubuntu install using the spare space inside the extended partition where you can create more logical partitions. Remember you don’t need a swap partition these days, the installer will create a swap file.

For extra peace of mind I recommend you create a full system backup using the free version of Macrium Reflect in Windows. Make sure you create rescue media too. This will ensure you can restore the current configuration if things were to go wrong.